# Consigo que me seleccione el valor, pero pierdo los datos al darle al submit y no consigo que persistan los datos

Tags: javascript, php, html

Estoy haciendo un option select, donde lo mando a una base de datos al acceder, y intentando darle persistencia de datos para que este no se borre, no llego a conseguirlo.
Pego el fragmento de código a ver si podéis echarme un cable Gracias !.

***Antes y después de enviar el Form***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podéis ver los demás datos se conservan, pero el campo select no.

```
 <div class="page-header align-items-start min-vh-100" style="background-image: url('front-end/img/fondo-formularios.jpg');" loading="lazy">
    <span class="mask bg-gradient-dark opacity-6"></span>
    <div class="container my-auto">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-8 col-12 mx-auto">
          <div class="card fondo-login z-index-0 fadeIn3 fadeInBottom">
            <div class="card-header p-0 position-relative mt-n4 mx-3 z-index-2">
              <div class="fondo-del-titulo shadow-acceder border-radius-lg py-3 pe-1">
                <h4 class="text-white font-weight-bolder text-center mt-2 mb-0 titulo-de-form">Formulario de Acceso</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
            <p class="text-center">
              <?php
              require_once 'back_end/conexion_de_bbdd/config_bd.php';
              if (isset($_SESSION["admin_login"])) {
                header("Location: panel_admin/inicio.php");
              }
              if (isset($_SESSION["colaborador_login"])) {
                header("Location: panel_colaborador/inicio.php");
              }
              if (isset($_SESSION["normal_login"])) {
                header("Location: panel/usuario.php");
              }

              if (isset($_POST['btn_login'])) {

                $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
                $password = $_POST["password"];
                $rol = $_POST["id_rol"];
                $_SESSION["usuario"] = $_POST["nombre"];

                if (empty($nombre)) {
                  $errorMsg[] = "Por favor ingrese Nombre"; //Revisar email
                } else if (empty($password)) {
                  $errorMsg[] = "Por favor ingrese Password"; //Revisar password vacio
                } else if (empty($rol)) {
                  $errorMsg[] = "Por favor seleccione Rol "; //Revisar rol vacio
                } else if ($nombre and $password and $rol) {
                  try {
                    $select_stmt = $bd->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_rol=:urol AND  nombre=:unombre AND password=:upassword");
                    $select_stmt->bindParam(":unombre", $nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $select_stmt->bindParam(":upassword", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $select_stmt->bindParam(":urol", $rol, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $select_stmt->execute();

                    while ($row = $select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                      $bdnombre = $row["nombre"];
                      $bdpassword = $row["password"];
                      $bdrol = $row["id_rol"];
                    }
                    //Descomentar en caso de error
                    // $select_stmt->debugDumpParams();
                    // var_dump($row);

                    if ($nombre != null & $password != null & $rol != null) {
                      if ($select_stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                        if ($nombre == $bdnombre & $password == $bdpassword & $rol == $bdrol) {
                          switch ($bdrol) {
                            case "1":
                              $_SESSION["admin_login"] = $nombre;
                              $_SESSION["admin_login"] = $rol;

                              $loginMsg = "Inicio sesión con éxito";
                              header("refresh:3; panel_admin/inicio.php");
                              break;

                            case "2";
                              $_SESSION["colaborador_login"] = $nombre;
                              $_SESSION["colaborador_login"] = $rol;
                              $loginMsg = "Inicio sesión con éxito";
                              header("refresh:3; panel_colaborador/inicio.php");
                              break;

                            case "3":
                              $_SESSION["normal_login"] = $nombre;
                              $_SESSION["normal_login"] = $rol;
                              $loginMsg = "Inicio sesión con éxito";
                              header("refresh:3; panel_usuario/inicio.php");
                              break;

                            default:
                              $errorMsg[] = "El usuario no existe en la aplicación.";
                          }
                        } else {
                          $errorMsg[] = "El usuario no existe en la aplicación.";
                        }
                      } else {
                        $errorMsg[] = "El usuario no existe en la aplicación.";
                      }
                    } else {
                      $errorMsg[] = "El usuario no existe en la aplicación.";
                    }
                  } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    $e->getMessage();
                  }
                } else {
                  $errorMsg[] = "El nombre o contraseña o rol incorrectos";
                }
              }
              ?>
            <div class="card-body">
              <form role="form" class="text-start" method="POST">
                <div class="input-group input-group-dynamic mb-4 my-3">
                  <i class="fa fa-user form-icons-acceder" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control inputs-tipo-letra" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php if (isset($nombre)) echo $nombre ?>">
                </div>

                <div class="input-group input-group-dynamic mb-4 my-3">
                  <i class="fa fa-key form-icons-acceder" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control inputs-tipo-letra" placeholder="Contraseña" value="<?php if (isset($password)) echo $password ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12">

                  <div class="input-group input-group-dynamic input-group-custom">
                    <i class="fa fa-cog form-icons-acceder" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <select name="id_rol" id="id_rol" class="form-select form-select-custom-acceder" onChange="imprimirValor()">
                      <option>Selecciona un rol</option>
                      <?php
                      $query_rol = $bd->query("SELECT id_rol,privilegios FROM rol AS rol WHERE rol.privilegios = 'Administrador' OR rol.privilegios = 'Colaborador' OR rol.privilegios = 'Normal';");
                      $resultado_tipo_rol = $query_rol->fetchAll();

                       foreach ($resultado_tipo_rol as $roles) {
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $roles["id_rol"]; ?>" <?php if ($roles["id_rol"] == $rol) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>
                        <?php echo $roles["privilegios"]; ?>
                    </option>
                    <?php
                }
                      ?>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="text-center">
                  <input class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-secondary my-3" type="submit" name="btn_login" value="Iniciar Sesión" />
                </div>

                <p class="mt-4 text-sm text-center texto-normal">
                  No tienes cuenta ?
                  <a href="registrarse.php" class="text-success text-gradient font-weight-bold texto-normal">Registrate</a>
                </p>
                <hr>


                <small class="text-muted texto-para-verificar">
                  <?php
                  if (isset($errorMsg)) {
                    foreach ($errorMsg as $error) {
                  ?>
                      <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <strong class="text-dark"><?php echo $error; ?></strong>
                      </div>
                    <?php
                    }
                  }
                  if (isset($loginMsg)) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                      <strong class="text-dark"><?php echo $loginMsg; ?> </strong>
                    </div>
                  <?php
                  }
                  ?>
                </small>
                </p>
              </form>
              <?php
              if ($bd == true) {
                echo "<p class='text-center estado-de-la-conexion'>
                            Aplicación conectada. <i class='fa fa-check-circle text-success' aria-hidden='true'></i>
                      </p>";
              }
              ?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Sobre el cambio realizado en dicho script del formulario me sale el siguiente error.
Al tener la variable declarada que imprime los valores como **$roles**, no detecta la variable almacenada en post como he dicho para que quede seleccionado **$rol = $_POST["id_rol"]** y no se borre del formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El comportamiento normal de un formulario al hacer `submit` es que se refresque la página y por ende, se "pierdan" los datos del formulario. Si deseas evitar ese comportamiento, puedes usar `ajax` para enviar los datos del formulario.

Comment: Suponiendo que el valor seleccionado lo has guardado en base de datos, tienes que recuperarlo y, al pintar las options del select, ponerle la propiedad selected a la option que tiene ese valor.

Comment: edito el código y os muestro como conservo los datos en los otros campos para que veais como se queda aunque me imagino que os haréis una idea jeje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues eso, como te decía en mi comentario, igual que le pones el valor al nombre y al password, al pintar las options del select tienes que ponerle la propiedad selected a la option que deba ser la seleccionada. Te pongo código por si no entiendes lo que te digo.

Suponiendo que el valor a marcar de rol lo tienes en una variable llamada $rol

```
foreach ($resultado_tipo_rol as $roles) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $roles["id_rol"]; ?>" <?php if ($roles["id_rol"] == $rol) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>>
        <?php echo $roles["privilegios"]; ?>
    </option>
    <?php
}
```

Nota: El if(isset($roles)) te sobraba.

**Para evitar Undefined variable**

Les doy un valor por defecto a las variables antes de comprobar si se ha enviado el formulario.

```
$nombre = '';
$password = '';
$rol = '';
if (isset($_POST['btn_login'])) {
    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $rol = $_POST["id_rol"];
    $_SESSION["usuario"] = $_POST["nombre"];
    
    //..........................
    //..........................
    //..........................
}
```

Comment: Se sigue borrando al darle al submit aunque lo seleccione

Comment: Lo que pretendo es que se conserve el dato seleccionado no se quede en seleccionar rol como mostraba en la foto

Comment: Sí, yo te he entendido desde el principio, ¿has entendido tú que tienes que tener el dato seleccionado guardado en algún sitio? En mi ejemplo, se supone que lo tienes recuperado en la variable $id_rol. Igual que tienes el valor de password en $password, tienes que tener el valor de id_rol, yo he dado por supuesto $id_rol, si ésta variable no la tienes, pues tendrás que ponerla. En tu código no muestras de dónde sacas $password, pero de forma similar tienes que recuperar el valor que hay que marcar en el select de rol.

Comment: Ok dame un segundo y pongo el formu entero, así aclaramos dudas restantes jeje

Comment: He editado la pregunta y actualizado la parte del formulario para que se vea todo entero, haber si así me aclaro !

Comment: Vale, ahí veo que la variable en la que guardas el rol es $rol, yo acabo de cambiar en mi respuesta $id_rol por $rol para que coincida con tu código. Pruébalo a ver.

Comment: pongo una captura sobre el cambio para que veas lo que ocurre con la variable $rol cambiada en el código

Comment: Edito mi respuesta para evitar Undefined variable.

Comment: Lo pruebo y te comento

Comment: Ahora sí ! muchas gracias José Carlos por la ayuda, pongo la respuesta para dar el ok valido ! un saludo

Comment: De nada. Estaría guay que valorases mi respuesta positivamente, e incluso que la dieses por buena, en vez de escribir tu propia respuesta.

Comment: echo ! gracias de nuevo ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Bueno hay que decir que tenia que declarar las variables fuera en un string vacío y para que pueda ir recorriendolas, y asignarle un valor después, de esta forma el valor queda almacenado y no se borra, dejo el código.

```
<div class="page-header align-items-start min-vh-100" style="background-image: url('front-end/img/fondo-formularios.jpg');" loading="lazy">
    <span class="mask bg-gradient-dark opacity-6"></span>
    <div class="container my-auto">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-8 col-12 mx-auto">
          <div class="card fondo-login z-index-0 fadeIn3 fadeInBottom">
            <div class="card-header p-0 position-relative mt-n4 mx-3 z-index-2">
              <div class="fondo-del-titulo shadow-acceder border-radius-lg py-3 pe-1">
                <h4 class="text-white font-weight-bolder text-center mt-2 mb-0 titulo-de-form">Formulario de Acceso</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
            <p class="text-center">
              <?php
              require_once 'back_end/conexion_de_bbdd/config_bd.php';
              if (isset($_SESSION["admin_login"])) {
                header("Location: panel_admin/inicio.php");
              }
              if (isset($_SESSION["colaborador_login"])) {
                header("Location: panel_colaborador/inicio.php");
              }
              if (isset($_SESSION["normal_login"])) {
                header("Location: panel/usuario.php");
              }

              $nombre = '';
              $password = '';
              $rol = '';

              if (isset($_POST['btn_login'])) {
                $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
                $password = $_POST["password"];
                $rol = $_POST["id_rol"];
                $_SESSION["usuario"] = $_POST["nombre"];

                if (empty($nombre)) {
                  $errorMsg[] = "Por favor ingrese Nombre"; //Revisar email
                } else if (empty($password)) {
                  $errorMsg[] = "Por favor ingrese Password"; //Revisar password vacio
                } else if (empty($rol)) {
                  $errorMsg[] = "Por favor seleccione Rol "; //Revisar rol vacio
                } else if ($nombre and $password and $rol) {
                  try {
                    $select_stmt = $bd->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id_rol=:urol AND  nombre=:unombre AND password=:upassword");
                    $select_stmt->bindParam(":unombre", $nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $select_stmt->bindParam(":upassword", $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $select_stmt->bindParam(":urol", $rol, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $select_stmt->execute();

                    while ($row = $select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                      $bdnombre = $row["nombre"];
                      $bdpassword = $row["password"];
                      $bdrol = $row["id_rol"];
                    }
                    //Descomentar en caso de error
                    // $select_stmt->debugDumpParams();
                    // var_dump($row);

                    if ($nombre != null & $password != null & $rol != null) {
                      if ($select_stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                        if ($nombre == $bdnombre & $password == $bdpassword & $rol == $bdrol) {
                          switch ($bdrol) {
                            case "1":
                              $_SESSION["admin_login"] = $nombre;
                              $_SESSION["admin_login"] = $rol;

                              $loginMsg = "Inicio sesión con éxito";
                              header("refresh:3; panel_admin/inicio.php");
                              break;

                            case "2";
                              $_SESSION["colaborador_login"] = $nombre;
                              $_SESSION["colaborador_login"] = $rol;
                              $loginMsg = "Inicio sesión con éxito";
                              header("refresh:3; panel_colaborador/inicio.php");
                              break;

                            case "3":
                              $_SESSION["normal_login"] = $nombre;
                              $_SESSION["normal_login"] = $rol;
                              $loginMsg = "Inicio sesión con éxito";
                              header("refresh:3; panel_usuario/inicio.php");
                              break;

                            default:
                              $errorMsg[] = "El usuario no existe en la aplicación.";
                          }
                        } else {
                          $errorMsg[] = "El usuario no existe en la aplicación.";
                        }
                      } else {
                        $errorMsg[] = "El usuario no existe en la aplicación.";
                      }
                    } else {
                      $errorMsg[] = "El usuario no existe en la aplicación.";
                    }
                  } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    $e->getMessage();
                  }
                } else {
                  $errorMsg[] = "El nombre o contraseña o rol incorrectos";
                }
              }
              ?>
            <div class="card-body">
              <form role="form" class="text-start" method="POST">
                <div class="input-group input-group-dynamic mb-4 my-3">
                  <i class="fa fa-user form-icons-acceder" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control inputs-tipo-letra" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php if (isset($nombre)) echo $nombre ?>">
                </div>

                <div class="input-group input-group-dynamic mb-4 my-3">
                  <i class="fa fa-key form-icons-acceder" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control inputs-tipo-letra" placeholder="Contraseña" value="<?php if (isset($password)) echo $password ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12">

                  <div class="input-group input-group-dynamic input-group-custom">
                    <i class="fa fa-cog form-icons-acceder" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <select name="id_rol" id="id_rol" class="form-select form-select-custom-acceder" onChange="imprimirValor()">
                      <option>Selecciona un rol</option>
                      <?php
                      $query_rol = $bd->query("SELECT id_rol,privilegios FROM rol AS rol WHERE rol.privilegios = 'Administrador' OR rol.privilegios = 'Colaborador' OR rol.privilegios = 'Normal';");
                      $resultado_tipo_rol = $query_rol->fetchAll();

                      foreach ($resultado_tipo_rol as $roles) {
                      ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $roles["id_rol"]; ?>" <?php if ($roles["id_rol"] == $rol) {
                                                                          echo 'selected="selected"';
                                                                        } ?>>
                          <?php echo $roles["privilegios"]; ?>
                        </option>
                      <?php
                      }
                      ?>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="text-center">
                  <input class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-secondary my-3" type="submit" name="btn_login" value="Iniciar Sesión" />
                </div>

                <p class="mt-4 text-sm text-center texto-normal">
                  No tienes cuenta ?
                  <a href="registrarse.php" class="text-success text-gradient font-weight-bold texto-normal">Registrate</a>
                </p>
                <hr>


                <small class="text-muted texto-para-verificar">
                  <?php
                  if (isset($errorMsg)) {
                    foreach ($errorMsg as $error) {
                  ?>
                      <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <strong class="text-dark"><?php echo $error; ?></strong>
                      </div>
                    <?php
                    }
                  }
                  if (isset($loginMsg)) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                      <strong class="text-dark"><?php echo $loginMsg; ?> </strong>
                    </div>
                  <?php
                  }
                  ?>
                </small>
                </p>
              </form>
              <?php
              if ($bd == true) {
                echo "<p class='text-center estado-de-la-conexion'>
                            Aplicación conectada. <i class='fa fa-check-circle text-success' aria-hidden='true'></i>
                      </p>";
              }
              ?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```